# Fisher information

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fisher-information

Hello how to show the following:

Observations $(X_1,X_2,..,X_n,)$ are i.i.d. over $[0,2\pi)$ with density 
$f(x,\theta) = \exp[\theta_1\cos x + \theta_2 \sin x -c(\theta)]$ where 
$\theta =(\theta_1,\theta_2) \in R^2$

Find an expression for the Fisher information $I(\theta)$ involving integrals and show that it is positive definite for all $\theta \in R^2$

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the definition of $I(\theta)$?

Comment: Yes @Zen i do but how to show the positive definiteness?

Comment: It is proved here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49942/why-is-the-fisher-information-matrix-positive-semidefinite/49961#49961